# Sql 'LEFT JOIN' two Tables that each Have 'Where' (not The join Condition )

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

this Left Join  query works well:

```
SELECT * FROM `Articles`  
  LEFT JOIN `uploaders` ON 
   uploaders.username=Articles.Poster
   ORDER BY `DATE` ASC  LIMIT 5;
```

but when adding a 'Where' to the first table

```
 SELECT * FROM `Articles`  WHERE `Content` OR `Title` LIKE '%somthing'
  LEFT JOIN `uploaders` ON 
   uploaders.username=Articles.Poster
   ORDER BY `DATE` ASC  LIMIT 5;
```

I get syntax error.
and I try to name the first result but still the same error

1:

```
SELECT * FROM `Articles`  WHERE `Content` OR `Title` LIKE '%somthing' AS art
  LEFT JOIN `uploaders` ON 
   uploaders.username=art.Poster
   ORDER BY `DATE` ASC  LIMIT 5;
```

2:

```
(SELECT * FROM `Articles`  WHERE `Content` OR `Title` LIKE '%somthing')Art
  LEFT JOIN `uploaders` ON 
   uploaders.username=Art.Poster
   ORDER BY `DATE` ASC  LIMIT 5;
```

What am I doing wrong? and if not this way how else can I do this?

Comment: Put the `where` clause after your join condition.

Comment: you know you can add the `where` at the end of the `JOIN` condition..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the where is **after** the join:

```
SELECT * FROM `Articles`  
  LEFT JOIN `uploaders` ON 
   uploaders.username=Articles.Poster
WHERE `Content` LIKE '%somthing' OR `Title` LIKE '%somthing'
   ORDER BY `DATE` ASC  LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: "WHERE `Content` OR `Title` LIKE '%somthing' " wouldn't work though.

Comment: you're right, I updated the answer. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3):

```
 SELECT * FROM `Articles` 
 LEFT JOIN `uploaders` ON 
   uploaders.username=Articles.Poster
 WHERE `Content` LIKE '%somthing' OR `Title` LIKE '%somthing'
 ORDER BY `DATE` ASC  LIMIT 5;
```